# NameError: undefined local variable or method `post' for #<FactoryGirl.Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory

I try to refactoring my specs.I have view **spec/views/posts.html.haml_spec.rb**

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe 'posts/show' do
  before(:each) do
    @post = assign(:post, create(:post))
    @comments = assign(:comment, Kaminari.paginate_array([
      create(:comment, post: @post)
    ]).page(1))
  end

  it 'renders attributes in <p>' do
    render
  end
end
```

and I want transfer of the code to factory **spec/factories/posts.rb**

```
FactoryGirl.define do

  factory :post do
    title Faker::Lorem.word
    body Faker::Lorem.paragraph


    trait :with_comments do
      after(:create) do
        create_list(:comment, post: post)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

but when I running  `FactoryGirl.create(:post, :with_comments)`, shell show me an error

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `post' for #<FactoryGirl::SyntaxRunner:0x00000003b44f08>
```

how fix?

sorry for my bad English

Comment: `create_list(:comment, post: post)`. What is the local variable `post` there? Should it be `:post`?

Comment: `create_list(:comment, post: create(:post))` it should be something like this lets you have `post factory`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't pass object to `after_create` block. You also didn;t specify the number of comments to be created. Change your trait to:

```
trait :with_comments do
  after(:create) do |post|
    create_list(:comment, <number_of_comments>, post: post)
  end
end
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, but shell render another error. NoMethodError: undefined method `times' for #<Hash:0x000000083c1da8>

Comment: That's because you haven't specify number of comments to be created.

Comment: It is explained in my answer?

Comment: because that's how 'create_list(:comment, 5, post: post)' is don't working

Comment: sorry, all it works.It was necessary to restart 'spring'

Comment: Thank you. Found this because of the `NoMethodError` I was getting too with build_list. I think FactoryGirl and I have been working together for too many hours straight.  I can't believe I overlooked that. /facepalm.